# cyclonedx dependsOn format includes a pipe

Tags: cyclonedx

I have a CycloneDX-formatted sbom that includes this snippet. What does the pipe character in the dependsOn array mean?

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Comment: Sorry, the image is from a secure system. I cannot copy/paste from it. I am not retyping it.

Answer (score 1):

> What does the pipe character in the dependsOn array mean?

nothing in particular.

The values in the `dependencies` are references to `bom-ref` in the same document. see the [docs](https://cyclonedx.org/docs/1.5/json/#dependencies).
The `bom-ref` is an arbitrary string that must be unique in the document. The values do not need to have any meaning. see the [docs](https://cyclonedx.org/docs/1.5/json/#compositions_items_bom-ref).

see also: https://github.com/CycloneDX/cyclonedx-node-npm/blob/main/docs/result.md